# Why do I get 'ImportError' for a Python function within multiple sub-directories?

Tags: python

I am using code from this [website](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/tree/develop/src)

There is a function called '`label_to_one_hot_batch`' within the file `isprs.py.

In my own python script in the main directory folder (i.e., the `semseg` folder), I am trying to import this function as follows:

```
from data.isprs import label_to_one_hot_batch
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name label_to_one_hot_batch
```

Any insight to solve this error would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label_to_one_hot_batch` is an instance method, so calling it outside of the context of the class makes little sense. You'd want to import `IsprsDataset`, instantiate it, and call that method on that instance.

For instance:

```
from data.isprs import IsprsDataset
dataset = IsprsDataset()
dataset.label_to_one_hot_batch(label_batch) # where label_batch is defined elsewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many reasons, I know, about two.

One is when PYTHON_PATH is not properly specified and the root of the python project is not recognized.

The second is when a cyclic import occurs where the importing module ultimately imports certain module again.